# Alphabetizing multidimensional array with SQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm working on programming a gradebook, and I've ran into a bit of an issue I'm trying to figure out how to approach.

I have three tables which are at play in this script: (1) the "assignments" table which contains info about each assignment, (2) the "assignGrades" table which contains student scores on assignments (3) the "students" table which contains student information.

Now, the problem is coming whenever I add a new student to the class. Logically, if a student joins a class mid-semester, they would not be assigned "past work" from earlier in the year. With this in mind, there would be no "connection" for an INNER JOIN statement. I have already tried using "LEFT JOIN" and "RIGHT JOIN" in this instance, but I am not having any luck.

Whenever I go to build a PHP array with the SQL statement below, I am running into a problem. If a student was added mid year, they are not properly alphabetizing into the array, which comes from the SELECT statement and the way this is organized. See the example below for student "Amy Appleton" which was added mid year, and is not in proper alphabetical order.

**HOW I NEED HELP / DESIRED END RESULT:**
I am trying to determine how to alphabetize my `$array` to be organized in order of last name. I have determined I will either accomplish this through rewriting my SQL statement or through using some sort of PHP `usort`, although I would much rather organize data on the SQL side if possible. My best guess would be to accomplish this through a LEFT JOIN, but I have tried every variation possible within my SQL statement and have not gotten any desired results.

**SQL statement used:**

```
SELECT students.firstName, students.lastName, assignments.assID, assignments.assEmoji, assignments.points, assignments.title, assignments.assigned, assignments.due, assignGrades.* 

FROM students 
LEFT JOIN assignGrades ON students.usid = assignGrades.usid 
LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignGrades.assID = assignments.assID

WHERE subID=? OR subID IS NULL ORDER BY due, lastName, firstName
```

**Snipet from PHP that is building the `$array`**

```
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
              $array['assignments'][$row['assID']]['assEmoji'] = $row['assEmoji'];
              $array['assignments'][$row['assID']]['title'] = $row['title'];
              $array['assignments'][$row['assID']]['points'] = $row['points'];
              $array['assignments'][$row['assID']]['assigned'] = $row['assigned'];
              $array['assignments'][$row['assID']]['due'] = $row['due'];
              $array['students'][$row['usid']]['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];
              $array['students'][$row['usid']]['lastName'] = $row['lastName'];
              $array['students'][$row['usid']]['fullName'] = $row['firstName']." ". $row['lastName'];
              if ($row['status'] == 'graded' || $row['status'] == 'missing') {
                $array['students'][$row['usid']]['earned'] = $array['students'][$row['usid']]['earned'] + $row['score'];
                $array['students'][$row['usid']]['maxpts'] = $array['students'][$row['usid']]['maxpts'] + $row['points'];
              }
              $array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['workID'] = $row['workID'];
              $array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['status'] = $row['status'];
              if (isset($row['submitted'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['submitted'] = $row['submitted'];}
              if (isset($row['method'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['method'] = $row['method'];}
              if (isset($row['score'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['score'] = $row['score'];}
              if (isset($row['score'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['points'] = $row['points'];}
              if (isset($row['graded'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['graded'] = $row['graded'];}
              if (isset($row['method'])) {$array['students'][$row['usid']]['submissions'][$row['assID']]['method'] = $row['method'];}
            }
            return $array;
```

**Example `print_r($array)` from the SQL statement** (Amy Appleton should appear on the top of `$array['students']` since she is alphabetically before the other two students. However, since there is no entry on the assignGrades table for assignment #9 for her, she appears at the bottom)

```
Array
(
    [assignments] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [assEmoji] => ✏️
                    [title] => Beginning of Year Activities
                    [points] => 10
                    [assigned] => 2021-08-16
                    [due] => 2021-08-20 15:00:00
                )
                
              [10] => Array
                  (
                      [assEmoji] => ✏️
                      [title] => Mid Year Project
                      [points] => 10
                      [assigned] => 2021-09-23
                      [due] => 2021-09-30 15:00:00
                  )
                  
        )

    [students] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => Zeke
                    [lastName] => Lee
                    [fullName] => Zeke Lee
                    [earned] => 103
                    [maxpts] => 120
                    [submissions] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [workID] => 539
                                    [status] => graded
                                    [submitted] => 2021-08-17 08:15:48
                                    [method] => wall
                                    [score] => 9
                                    [points] => 10
                                    [graded] => 2021-09-22 10:26:54
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [workID] => 541
                                    [status] => graded
                                    [submitted] => 2021-09-23 08:15:48
                                    [method] => wall
                                    [score] => 9
                                    [points] => 10
                                    [graded] => 2021-09-23 10:26:54
                                )

                        )

                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => John
                    [lastName] => Smith
                    [fullName] => John Smith
                    [earned] => 91
                    [maxpts] => 110
                    [submissions] => Array
                        (
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [workID] => 540
                                    [status] => graded
                                    [submitted] => 2021-08-17 08:45:48
                                    [method] => wall
                                    [score] => 7
                                    [points] => 10
                                    [graded] => 2021-09-22 10:28:54
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [workID] => 590
                                    [status] => graded
                                    [submitted] => 2021-09-23 09:15:48
                                    [method] => wall
                                    [score] => 9
                                    [points] => 10
                                    [graded] => 2021-09-23 11:24:54
                                )

                        )

                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [firstName] => Amy
                    [lastName] => Appleton
                    [fullName] => Amy Appleton
                    [earned] => 91
                    [maxpts] => 110
                    [submissions] => Array
                        (
                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [workID] => 913
                                    [status] => graded
                                    [submitted] => 2021-09-23 10:45:48
                                    [method] => wall
                                    [score] => 7
                                    [points] => 10
                                    [graded] => 2021-09-23 12:31:54
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Array structure:**

$array['assignments'][*assID*][**details**]

$array['students'][*usid*][**details**]

$array['students'][*usid*]['submissions'][*assID*][**details**]

**Screenshots of table structure from SQL**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Screenshot of CSV dump from SQL query**
[image]

Comment: Your query is selecting from _assignments_ which will be empty for Amy Appleton. You should select from _students_ and then left join to _assignments_ and _assignGrades_.

Comment: @waterloomatt right, that was what I thought too. I tried this query but got the same result. ```FROM students LEFT JOIN assignGrades ON students.usid = assignGrades.usid LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignGrades.assID = assignments.assID```

Comment: Right. So now, Amy should be showing up in the result set but her assignments and grades will be empty so you need to change your PHP to account for that. Perhaps edit your question with more details after making this change.

Comment: @waterloomatt I don't believe the issue would be PHP. Whenever I run the SQL statement inside MySQL, there are no entries in the "query results" which show that a left join occurred (IE: only a name, no assignment/grade details). Would it help to drop a link to a CSV dump from the query?

Comment: No, please edit your question with these details. Please include all relevant information so we don't need to have extended chats here. Is your query filtering on subjects with `WHERE subID=?`? Amy would never show up there because she doesn't have any _assignments.subID_. Also, please include what your desired output should look like. Depending on that, it might be easier to use multiple queries to get your desired data structure.

Comment: @waterloomatt edited OG post for clarification. I tried including "OR subID IS NULL" and still do not get any results. Also attached the CSV dump screenshot. See post, it says "Amy Appleton should appear on the top of $array['students'] since she is alphabetically before the other two students. "

Comment: `ORDER BY due, lastName, firstName` Why are you ordering by _due_ if you want it sorted by last name?

Comment: @waterloomatt for the ```$array['assignments']``` to be in proper order based on due date

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that your query is trying to do too much. It is trying to get assignments in a specific order (*by due*), as well as students and their submissions in a different order (*by lastName, firstName*). For this reason, I would break this up into 2 separate queries. You can combine the datasets later to make your final data structure.

1. retrieve the assignments and order them by *due date*. This is a very simple query and the result set can be used directly.
2. retrieve all students and their submissions, if they exist, and order them by *lastName, first name*. Then, in PHP, manipulate the dataset into the format you need.

Pseudocode

```
// Get assignments. These can be used directly in your data structure `$combined`. 
// 
// Order by due date
$assignments = SELECT ... FROM assignments   
               WHERE ... 
               ORDER BY due;


// Get students and their assignments. These need to be manipulated to fit your
// requirements. Use a left join here because a student may not have started 
// an assignment yet. 
// 
// Order by lastName, firstName
$students = SELECT ... FROM students a 
            LEFT JOIN assignGrades b ON b.usid = a.usid 
            ORDER BY lastName, firstName;

// See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9460c51954f8ea00f7ba75adadfcbf91fc03076e

// Loop over the student/submission dataset and manipulate it.     
$studentMapping = [];
foreach($students as $row) {
    // Build up student data if it doesn't already exist. 
    // Importantly, create an empty submissions element. If the student's 
    // submission doesn't exist, this is what will be returned. 
    $student = $studentMapping[$row['usid']] ?? [];
    if (empty($student)) {
        $student = [
            'firstName' => $row['lastName'],
            'lastName' => $row['lastName'],  
            ...
            'submissions' => [],
        ];
    }
    
    // Build up submissions data for the student if they have submitted an assignment.
    // If they haven't submitted an assignment yet, their submissions array will remain empty.
    if (!empty($row['assignment_id'])) {
        $student['submissions'][] = [
            'assignmentId' => $row['assignment_id'],
            'status' => $row['status'],
            ...
        ];
        
    }    

    // Finally, assign the student (and their submissions) to the $studentMapping array. 
    $studentMapping[$row['usid']] = $student;
}

// Now combine them into your final datastructure. 
$combined = [
    'assignments' => $assignments,
    'students' => $studentMapping,
];
```